# How can i attach a separate instance of Javascript code to N angular views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-canvas

I have some HTML5 code, using canvas, which draws a graph. I am trying to create an Angular SPA which will draw N of these graphs, based on a model with N objects. Here is a simplified version of what I have done.

1. Created a Controller with an array of N objects. (Name, and Value).
2. Created a custom Angular directive called ccGraph, which brings in a HTML 5 Template.
3. Used ng-repeat to create N divs containing ccGraph elements. (ng-repeat conn in connections)

I am having a conceptual problem connecting everything up. If I just put {{conn.name}} in the HTML template, the name gets correctly displayed in each ccGraph div.

My problem is that I don't know how to attach an instance of my Javascript code for graphing to each ccGraph div. The Javascript code starts by finding the canvas it's embedded in, and works from there.

1. Will Angular create a separate instance of the Javascript code for each instance of ccGraph?
2. How might I go about "initialising" the Javascript code with the name of it's containing div? (In my standalone HTML code I used onLoad() to do all of the initial drawing.)

OK, from a code point-of-view, I have working index.HTML like this;

```
<BODY  onload="initialise();" >
<div class="usageMeter" width="200px" height="500px" > 
    <canvas id="testIndicator" class="usageScale" width="200px" height="500px" >
        Fallback content, in case the browser does not support Canvas.
    </canvas>
```

and Javascript code that draws a graph, like this:

```
function initialise() {
mCanvas = document.getElementById("testIndicator");
ctx = mCanvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);
scaleWidth = mCanvas.width * 0.4;
scaleHeight = mCanvas.height * 0.8;
scaleX = mCanvas.width * 0.25;
scaleY = mCanvas.height * 0.1;

loadImages();
drawScale();
elapsedTime = 0.0;
oldElapsedTime = 0.0;
tid = setInterval(updateTime, tickInterval);
}
```

Now, I want to use an Angular SPA to draw N of these graphs. So, let's just say that my Angular code is not started yet. How, conceptually, would I convert the above code to be an Angular directive, driven by an Angular Model?

Comment: sharing some of your code would help. :)

Comment: is this what you are trying to do? if yes I can make an answer explaining what happens. :) http://plnkr.co/edit/wgJo1gCnI9x9OKpuTlsp?p=preview

Comment: Absolutely, that's spot on. I will study your code to see how you do it. If you want to make a short answer with a basic explanation, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: sorry for the delay. I made an answer going a bit more in depth on what goes on. If something is still unclear please let me know and I will try to amend the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to think of implementing this using a directive. In angular 1 that is the way to attach behavior to DOM elements. They can also be instantiated multiple times, for example in an **ng-repeat**.

In your particular case about making a directive that is able to draw on a canvas. I would go about it this way.

```js
app.directive('painter', function($interval) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'painter.html', // the template to instantiate
    scope: {
      stuffToDraw: '=' // bind(2-way-binding) the stuff-to-draw attribute on the host element to scope.stuffToDraw (via reference)
    },
    // the link function gets called once for the directive
    // it is usually used in directives that do dom manipulation directly
    // will most likely be deprecated in angular 1.5
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // get the canvas from the template and the context to draw on the angular way
      // element is the host element of the directive
      var canvasCtx = element.children()[0].getContext('2d');

      canvasCtx.fillStyle = "red";

      var rotate = 0;
      var textToDraw = '';

      // add a watcher on the value in the scope so we know if/when it changes
      scope.$watch('stuffToDraw', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue) { // 1st time it will be undefined
          textToDraw = newValue;
        }
      });

      // save the interval promise so we can cancel it later when the directive is destroyed
      var intervalPromise = $interval(function() {
        rotate++;
        drawStuff();
      }, 30);

      // when the scope is destroyed (eg the element is removed from dom) stop the interval
      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
      });

      function drawStuff(newValue) {
        canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 500);
        canvasCtx.save();
        canvasCtx.translate(10, 200);
        canvasCtx.rotate(rotate);
        canvasCtx.translate(-10, -200);
        canvasCtx.fillText(textToDraw, 10, 200);
        canvasCtx.restore();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- painter.html -->
<!-- this content will be inserted in the painter(host) element -->
<canvas class="usageScale" width="200px" height="500px">
  Fallback content, in case the browser does not support Canvas.
</canvas>
```

```html
<!-- main/usage -->
<!-- itterate over the values array and instantiate a directive for each value. bind the array elements as the stuff-to-draw value (scope.stuffToDraw) -->
<!-- painter will be the host element for our directive instances -->
<painter ng-repeat="value in values" stuff-to-draw="value"></painter>
```

This is not the only way this could be implemented, you could've also done a lot of the work in the **controller**.

If you want to know more about how directive actually work you can find more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

The latest version of the plunker can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bRt5jEfwVwX1oivMsC9g?p=preview).